# Format a UITextField for currency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField on my aplication that receives only numeric input from the user. This numeric input represents currency and have the default value of 0.00.

I would like to create something like a mask to format the UITextField as the user enter the numbers. For example:

9 becomes $0,09
99 becomes $0,99
999 becomes $999,99

The code below works great, but as I'm using integer and float values the app will eventually display wrong values afeter a certain point. For example:

999999999 becomes 100000000

That happens because flot and integer aren't precise enough and NSDEcimalNumber should be used. The point is that I can't figure out how to replace my integers and float values to NSDecimalNumber ones.

Does anyone could give me a hand to solve this? I spend some time searching the web for a solution but didn't find that suits my needs and tons of people with the same problem.

Heres the code:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (textField.tag == 1){
    NSString *cleanCentString = [[textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSInteger centValue= cleanCentString.integerValue;

    if (string.length > 0)
    {
        centValue = centValue * 10 + string.integerValue;
    }
    else
    {
        centValue = centValue / 10;
    }

    NSNumber *formatedValue;
    formatedValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:(float)centValue / 100.0f];
    NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    textField.text = [_currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:formatedValue];
    return NO;
}

if (textField.tag == 2){
    // Nothing for now
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have a bigger issue. You are assuming the currency is being entered in 100ths of a currency value such as cents. People in Japan won't be happy since the Japanese Yen is only in whole Yen, for example. You should interrogate the number formatter after setting it to currency style and see how many decimal places it is setup for.

Comment: You're right, rmaddy. Back log keeps increasing =D

Comment: Personally I think it is better to simply let the user type in a raw number with no "format as you go" processing. Don't format the raw number until the user leaves the text field. As a user, I'd rather type in the decimal separator when I actually want a decimal. If I type `9` then I mean nine dollars, not nine cents. If I want nine cents then I want to type `.09`. Let the post processing format that to `$0.09` or whatever after I'm done typing. Don't make me type `900` to get nine dollars. But that's just one opinion.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting point. Maybe it's better.

Comment: @Carlos i m using ur method and got same issue.  i check the below answer but some how i cant fix that. can u please help me out on this. can u please edit the same method with correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert integer or double/float value to string by following:

```
NSString *str = [@(myInt) stringValue];
NSString *str1 = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] stringValue];
```

After that you can convert string to NSDecimalNumber by many ways. Like:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100.1"];
NSLog(@"%@", number);
NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100.1" locale:NSLocale.currentLocale];
NSLog(@"%@",num);
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);
```

NSNumberFormatter will help you with the right formatting. Please read apples page for [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
NSNumberFormatter contains a section named"Configuring the Format of Currency". I didn't try it, but it seems something that can help you.

Let me know if this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, Rashad! That worked prety fine to convert values from string to NSDecimalNumber, even for currencies. But now I'm getting 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException' because I'm doing this: result = [decimalValue decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:base]; and result = [decimalValue decimalNumberByDividingBy:base];.

Comment: @carlos >> Did you solved the problem? I was going through my answers. So I just asked. :)

Comment: I decided to change things a little bit and simply let the user type in a raw number. But I didn´t find a solution for the 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException error =/

Comment: It normally causes if numbers used in the operation are not valid numbers. Check your number carefully you can check with this: [NSDecimalNumber notANumber] before performing the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and add next methods:

**Swift:**

```
let currencySign = "$"

// Adds $ before the text, e.g. "1" -> "$1" and allows "." and ","
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
    var value = textField.text

    var newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    var components = newString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890,.").invertedSet)

    var decimalString = "".join(components) as NSString
    var length = decimalString.length

    if length > 0 {
        value = "\(currencySign)\(decimalString)"
    }
    else {
        value = ""
    }
    textField.text = value
}

// Formats final value using current locale, e.g. "130,50" -> "$130", "120.70" -> "$120.70", "5" -> "$5.00"
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        var value = textField.text
        var components = value.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890,.").invertedSet)
        var decimalString = "".join(components) as NSString

        let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: decimalString, locale:NSLocale.currentLocale())

        var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        if let formatedValue = formatter.stringFromNumber(number) {
            textField.text = formatedValue
        }
        else {
            textField.text = ""
        }
}
```