# How to format currency in text field

Tags: swift, textfield, number-formatting

I want users to see the price they enter formatted as they type into the text field. Specifically they would be entering prices only in US dollars, so I do not have to worry about formatting other currencies. How would I go from the text in a textfield to displaying a nicely formatted currency amount? Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078572/format-a-uitextfield-for-currency

Comment: what platform is this running on?

Comment: Also see the documentation for Measurement in Foundation if you are using Swift 3 and iOS 10 SDK.