# Format UITextField for dollar input from user in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to get a better grasp of delegates and I am trying to create a dollar sign field that begins with the text $0.00, and then fills in the dollar figure as digits are added. For example, typing 4-2-7-5 would produce $0.00, $0.04, $0.42, $4.27, $42.75.

I have created a UITextField and a delegate file for this behavior. I have no idea how to proceed and I am a complete noob in this concept. I found a thread that does explore this concept, but the thread is far more advanced and I don't understand the syntax being used. That question is at: [Format a UITextField for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078572/format-a-uitextfield-for-currency)

I really want to know how to make this happen, but more importantly WHY it works.

Comment: Can you explain what parts of the code from the other answer you are struggling to understand? Then answer in that question is perfect for what you need. So please explain what you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: You bet. That answer has syntax already written out and I am not following how he/she arrived at that logic. I am struggling with starting to tackle this problem.